# How to fix TypeError when using signInWithCredential on node.js? [EDIT: bug in Firebase 6.2.2]

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I am trying to sign in to firebase using a Google Id Token, as I'm developing an app that will be running on a raspberry pi, but when trying to sign in using the received token firebase crashes when using signInWithCredential. Here's my minimal reproducible example

```
var firebase = require("firebase/app");
require("firebase/auth");

const firebaseConfig = {
    ...
};
  // Initialize Firebase

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const id_token = "A_GOOGLE_ID_TOKEN";

var credential = firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(id_token);
firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(credential);
```

and it crashes with

```
TypeError: this.f is not a constructor
    at ai.a (C:\Dev\Crashing\node_modules\@firebase\auth\dist\auth.js:188:361)
    at yh (C:\Dev\Crashing\node_modules\@firebase\auth\dist\auth.js:171:191)
    at bi.o (C:\Dev\Crashing\node_modules\@firebase\auth\dist\auth.js:193:175)
    at ji (C:\Dev\Crashing\node_modules\@firebase\auth\dist\auth.js:191:239)
    at C:\Dev\Crashing\node_modules\@firebase\auth\dist\auth.js:197:181
    at new C (C:\Dev\Crashing\node_modules\@firebase\auth\dist\auth.js:18:736)
    at pi (C:\Dev\Crashing\node_modules\@firebase\auth\dist\auth.js:197:161)
    at C:\Dev\Crashing\node_modules\@firebase\auth\dist\auth.js:209:203
    at e.g (C:\Dev\Crashing\node_modules\@firebase\auth\dist\auth.js:22:101)
    at Kb (C:\Dev\Crashing\node_modules\@firebase\auth\dist\auth.js:25:195)
```

I tried it with several valid ID Tokens, but it seems that part is actually not broken, the credential itself appears to be fine, because signInWithCredential dies the same way even when I pass an arbitrary string as the id_token.

What am I doing wrong? Or could it possibly be an issue with Firebase JS SDK itself?

I am working on Windows 10, ver. 1809, running Node v10.15.3 and firebase JS SDK 6.2.2 (npm firebase package).

**EDIT:** I tried Firebase JS SDK version 6.2.0 and the code worked as expected! There is a bug in version 6.2.2 though.

Comment: For me, I had to do more than set firebase version, because it seems to have loose version dependencies on other libraries as noted in my comment to Doug below. I had to also fix the versions of those dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase JS SDK 6.2.3 was just released today, and it fixes this bug:
https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js#authentication

Look like this is the git commit that fixes it:
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/commit/728f4f54b4589c07a2d474deb94328a332c8fe39

I verified it with this mocha unit test:

```
const firebase = require('../../firebaseApp')
const chai = require('chai')

describe('firebase javascript sdk', () => {

  // This unit test verifies that the error message is as expected,
  // and not the error "this.f is not a constructor", which was caused
  // by a bug in version 6.2.1, and fixed in versin 6.2.3.
  // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56716255/how-to-fix-typeerror-when-using-signinwithcredential-on-node-js-edit-bug-in-f
  it('should be able to checkActionCode', () => {
    return firebase.auth().checkActionCode('xyz')
      .catch(error => {
        // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56716255/how-to-fix-typeerror-when-using-signinwithcredential-on-node-js-edit-bug-in-f
        chai.assert.equal(error.message,
          "The action code is invalid. This can happen if the code is malformed, expired, or has already been used.")
      })
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The Firebase client SDKs generally do not work with nodejs.  Firebase Authentication depends heavily on running inside a web browser in order to work correctly.

If you're running node, you might want to consider just using the Firebase Admin SDK to access your project without having to sign in.

Comment: Thanks, but according to https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/environments_js-sdk this method of authentication should be available in the client SDK. I didn't want to use the admin SDK, because the target use case is just basically a headless client authenticated to firebase, but it seems that in the end I'll have no other choice.

Comment: If I lock my package versions to the following, then it works to firebase.auth().checkActionCode() in a Cloud Function. But if I use the npm latest, then I also get this TypeError. So it seems that something was changed to break it in the last few months:
    "@firebase/app": "0.3.5",
    "@firebase/app-types": "0.3.2",
    "@firebase/auth": "0.9.1",
    "@firebase/auth-types": "0.5.0",

Comment: See related question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56728539/how-to-accomplish-firebase-auth-checkactioncode-using-firebase-auth-rest-sdk